# Why after installing GIMP on a Mac, it opens X11 and doesn't work?

Tags: macos, installation, xorg, gimp

I want to use GIMP on my Mac OS X 10.6.6.

I downloaded GIMP for Snow Leopard, double-clicked on the `.dmg` file, dragged the app into applications.

It seemed to be installed, so in Spotlight I type "gimp", find it, run it, but all it does it bring up the GIMP icon in the Dock, along with an X11 icon and window, but doesn't do anything else.

[image: GIMP and X11 icons in the Dock]

How do I get GIMP for Mac OS X installed?

Comment: Kill those applications from the Dock and try again. It's just incredibly slow and for some reason, has tons of disk activity.

Comment: You may want to update your X11 application.

Comment: @aqua It works for me with the bundled X11 of 10.6.6 (with the behavior I described in my comment).

Comment: @Daniel thanks, you were right, it just takes about 20 seconds to load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill those applications from the Dock and try again. It's just incredibly slow and for some reason, has tons of disk activity. That was my experience when I tried to reproduce the issue with an unmodified 10.6.6 X11.

Answer (score 1):

[Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html) is a popular native GIMP for Mac. It apparently has features missing, but I can't think of any from use (they must be obscure functions). X11 is good, but you'd be better off not using if you don't have to.